# maxOffsetsPerTrigger not honoured in Spark Streaming with Once Trigger setting

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Kafka Topic with 20 partitions. And trying to read that topic and dump the data in a DFS. I have the below code that reads the kafka topic.

```
streaming_df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.KAFKA_CONFIG["kafka_bootstrap_servers"]) \
.option("subscribe", config.KAFKA_CONFIG["subscribe"]) \
.option("failOnDataLoss", config.KAFKA_CONFIG["fail_on_data_loss"]) \
.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", config.KAFKA_CONFIG["max_offsets_per_trigger"]) \
.load()

query = streaming_df. \
        selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "partition_id"). \
        writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", config.GCS_STAGE_1_CHECKPOINT_LOCATION). \
        trigger(once=True). \
        foreachBatch(lambda df, epoch_id: process(df, epoch_id, config)).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I have set `config.KAFKA_CONFIG["max_offsets_per_trigger"]` value to be 30M.

But, stats from query.lastProgress shows that total records being fetched are always around 59999982 number, which is double of what I have mentioned in the maxOffsetsPerTrigger property.

PS: Topic has a lot of unread data. And Data is uniformly distributed among all the partitions in the topic.

Spark Version: 2.4.8
Kafka Package: org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.8

I have tried the same code with the exact same setting when data is comparatively less in the topic. And it has worked fine that time.

I am expecting the same to happen in all the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the `once` in `trigger` to `True`. When you check the Databricks document (https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/triggers.html#configuring-incremental-batch-processing):

> Apache Spark provides the .trigger(once=True) option to process all
> new data from the source directory as a single micro-batch. This
> trigger once pattern ignores all setting to control streaming input
> size, which can lead to massive spill or out-of-memory errors.

It will ignore your `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` setting. If you want to limit the number of records in each processing, you should remove the `.trigger()` configuration.

Comment: Not sure about Once trigger behaviour difference between databricks and GCP's data proc flavour. 
But, I have seen this property in action and working completely fine when unconsumed data in 2x-3x of the maxOffsetsPerTrigger. Only when unconsumed data grows beyond this, then I am facing this issue.